# Attributes.Add("class", "className") but preserve existing class

Tags: css, vb.net, class

Simple thing, well, I think it is.

I need to Add a class to an element within an asp:repeater under certain conditions, using VB.

So, I can do

```
ITEMID.Attributes.Add("class", "classToAdd")
```

But this removes the existing classes and therefore screws up my CSS.

```
ITEMID.Attributes("class") = "classToAdd"
```

Seems to do the same thing.

How do I *add* a class to an element, whilst preserving it's existing class values?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `+=` to add additional class, and make sure you leave a space before or else it will appear as `currentClassclassToAdd`, where current class is `currentClass`:

```
ITEMID.Attributes("class") += " classToAdd"
```

---

This is the same as doing:

```
ITEMID.Attributes("class") = ITEMID.Attributes("class") + " classToAdd"
```

Therefore:

```
ITEMID.Attributes("class") = "currentClass" + " classToAdd"
```

Comment: And for those of us using C# instead, this is the correct syntax: `ITEMID.Attributes["class"] += " classToAdd"`

Answer (score 3):

You need to stack them up:

```
Dim existingClasses as string = ITEMID.Attributes("class")

ITEMID.Attributes.Add("class", existingClasses & " classToAdd")
```